# Background audio controls: 15 second forward/rewind as in AudioBooks

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible and how to configure the app to show Fast-Forward/Rewind (15 seconds) buttons using iOS app instead of Next/Previous track. As it is working for AudioBooks in Music.app.

I'm trying to implement AudioPlayer using AVAudioPlayer/AVPlayer and use background controls.

I have implemented:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and I'm getting events on Play/Pause, NextTrack, PreviousTrack.

So I'm having this:

[image]

But would like to achieve this, in terms of Next/Prev buttons.

[image: background audiobook controls for fast-forward/rewind]

I think there is probably no such public API, but ...

Comment: "Is it possible?" - well, you have a working example so the answer must be 'yes'.  How to do it?  You'll have to add a lot more detail to your question before someone can give a reasonable and useful answer that doesn't start out with a tutorial on how to program iPhones.  See also [this excellent post](http://whathaveyoutried.com) for more info on how to ask a question that will get useful answers.

Comment: I ment Apple's Music.app can do that, but how to implement that in the app?

Comment: you're probably getting voted down because SO isn't a "how do I do it?" forum. It's more "this is what I tried, it doesn't work as expected, and here's my code"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't (*yet*)

That's an Apple-only thing, currently only available for their apps - specifically the Music and Podcasts apps.

However, iOS 7 should be introduced within a few months - watch for this functionality to be introduced in the next release.

Comment: Is there any solutions now? I tried googling, and I couldn't find much.

Comment: Is there any solutions yet? I could not see any documented in the "Event Handling Guide for iOS". Could it be documented anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the link below 
(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html
)

and solve the problem like this

```
- (IBAction)FifteenSecForward:(id)sender {
[self.player pause];
[self.player playAtTime:self.player.deviceCurrentTime - 15.0];
[self.player play];
```

}

**I think it will be helpful for you**

Comment: How does this provide the background audio controls with those ±15 seconds buttons to the control center or lock screen?